# How do you get total amount of RAM the computer has?

Tags: c#, memory, performancecounter

Using C#, I want to get the total amount of RAM that my computer has.
With the PerformanceCounter I can get the amount of Available ram, by setting:

```
counter.CategoryName = "Memory";
counter.Countername = "Available MBytes";
```

But I can't seem to find a way to get the total amount of memory.  How would I go about doing this?

**Update:**

MagicKat: I saw that when I was searching, but it doesn't work - "Are you missing an assembly or reference?". I've looked to add that to the References, but I don't see it there.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The Windows API function [`GlobalMemoryStatusEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-globalmemorystatusex) can be called with p/invoke:

```
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
  private class MEMORYSTATUSEX
  {
     public uint dwLength;
     public uint dwMemoryLoad;
     public ulong ullTotalPhys;
     public ulong ullAvailPhys;
     public ulong ullTotalPageFile;
     public ulong ullAvailPageFile;
     public ulong ullTotalVirtual;
     public ulong ullAvailVirtual;
     public ulong ullAvailExtendedVirtual;
     public MEMORYSTATUSEX()
     {
        this.dwLength = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(NativeMethods.MEMORYSTATUSEX));
     }
  }


  [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
  static extern bool GlobalMemoryStatusEx([In, Out] MEMORYSTATUSEX lpBuffer);
```

Then use like:

```
ulong installedMemory;
MEMORYSTATUSEX memStatus = new MEMORYSTATUSEX();
if( GlobalMemoryStatusEx( memStatus))
{ 
   installedMemory = memStatus.ullTotalPhys;
}
```

Or you can use WMI (managed but slower) to query `TotalPhysicalMemory` in the `Win32_ComputerSystem` class.

Comment: This is working! Thanks.
One thing though - TotalPhysical is giving how much is in use, AvailablePhysical is giving how much is left.  So get the real total, you have to add those up.  Thanks!

Comment: That's not working...
long ramuse = (long)stat.TotalPhysical;
long ramavailable = (long)stat.AvailablePhysical;
long ramtotal = ramavailable + ramuse;
int percent = (int)( (float)ramuse / ramtotal * 100);

percent is telling me "70" and total is constantly changing, give or take 100. should be 72%

Comment: Changed to GlobalMemoryStatusEx - GlobalMemoryStatus used uint and had problems - over 4GB would simply give garbage, but from 2GB-4GB would be rounded down to 2G for both avail and total.

Comment: The code works, only you dont need to use 'NativeMethods' to get the size of the object, you simply can say like this: `this.dwLength = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(this);` and it works the same (I had trouble with using NativeMethods so this fix now works).

Comment: "NativeMethods" is the namespace of the type.  The call to SizeOf can be changed if you prefer.

Comment: What is `GlobalMemoryStatusEx`? I cannot seem to find its refernce. Oh Man i get 0 on it all. Why is ti so freaking difficult to get memeory and cpu info in C#; blyme

Comment: Quote from MSDN: "The information returned by the GlobalMemoryStatusEx function is volatile. There is no guarantee that two sequential calls to this function will return the same information."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366589(v=vs.85).aspx - In my opinion this kind of renders the function totally useless

Comment: @Corelgott Useless because it gives up to date information?  I mean, everytime I check the weather channel it gives different information, but I wouldn't go so far as to call it totally useless.   I'm not even sure what you would want this function to do if it didn't return potentially different information each time - should it "lock" the results after the first invocation and then return stale data after that?   In what way would that be more useful?

Comment: A bit late to the party but I happened upon this thread and this answer is not correct. GlobalMemoryStatusEx doesn't necessarily (and often won't) give the actual amount of RAM installed on the machine, it gives the amount that is available to the OS which is almost always different than the amount installed due to reserved memory for drivers, etc. To get the actual amount of RAM installed you would want to call the GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory function which returns the proper total RAM.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc300158(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Can you use this on Windows CE? Typically you can PInvoke these on coredll.dll or kernel.dll, but these fail. The MSDN article for GlobalMemoryStatusEx doesn't say whether its available for WinCE, so I'm guessing not.

Comment: Not cross-platform!

Answer (score 190):

Add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and a `using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices;`.

The `ComputerInfo` class has all the information that you need.

Comment: Why on earth was this voted down? Voted back up! This is the easiest way to do it, and yes you can this from C#.

Comment: +1: Some people have an aversion to referencing the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace from C#, even though it's really just another assembly that's installed as a part of everything else.

Comment: Return negative junk value on Windows7 64bit with 8gb ram. Thats why you got down voted?

Comment: For anyone leery of using (new ComputerInfo()).TotalPhysicalMemory, it works fine on a system with even more memory than that. Its return type is unsigned long, so a negative number is not possible without an (invalid) cast.

Comment: var totalGBRam = Convert.ToInt32((new ComputerInfo().TotalPhysicalMemory / (Math.Pow(1024, 3))) + 0.5);

Comment: The `Devices` namespace [has been removed from .NET Core 3.0 onwards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/visualbasic#types-in-microsoftvisualbasicdevices-namespace-not-available), so this cannot be used on newer versions.

Comment: The Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace has no ComputerInfo class in .Net Framework 4.8. Also I was hoping to find a cross-platform (mono) solution

Answer (score 65):

Add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll, as someone mentioned above.  Then getting total physical memory is as simple as this (yes, I tested it):

```
static ulong GetTotalMemoryInBytes()
{
    return new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo().TotalPhysicalMemory;
}
```

Comment: @ppumkin, in what version of .NET, and in what version of Visual Studio?  When I run it in VS 2012 using .NET 4.5 on a 64-bit machine with 8 GB of RAM, it works fine.  I get back 8520327168.

Comment: .NET 4, VS2010 32bit on Windows Pro 7 64bit

Comment: Works fine on x64.You are using a 32 bit VS that is probably compiling 32 bit binaries that wont see full memory size.

Comment: When using this in Visual Studio 2017 with C# .Net 4.6.1, I did have to add a reference for Microsoft.VisualBasic to get this to work. 
Project > Add Reference >> Assemblies > Check Microsoft.VisualBasic >> OK

Comment: I noticed a difference between GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory and Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo().TotalPhysicalMemory

new FileSizeStruct(34173231104)
{31.8 GB}
    ByteCount: 34173231104
    ByteSize: GB
    Size: 31.8
new FileSizeStruct(34359738368)
{32 GB}
    ByteCount: 34359738368
    ByteSize: GB
    Size: 32

Answer (score 45):

All the answers here, including the accepted one, will give you the total amount of RAM ***available*** for use.  And that may have been what OP wanted.

But if you are interested in getting the amount of ***installed*** RAM, then you'll want to make a call to the [GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc300158(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

From the link, in the Remarks section:

> The **GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory** function retrieves the amount of physically installed RAM from the computer's SMBIOS firmware tables. This can differ from the amount reported by the **GlobalMemoryStatusEx** function, which sets the ullTotalPhys member of the MEMORYSTATUSEX structure to the amount of physical memory that is available for the operating system to use. ***The amount of memory available to the operating system can be less than the amount of memory physically installed in the computer*** because the BIOS and some drivers may reserve memory as I/O regions for memory-mapped devices, making the memory unavailable to the operating system and applications.

**Sample code:**

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory(out long TotalMemoryInKilobytes);

static void Main()
{
    long memKb;
    GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory(out memKb);
    Console.WriteLine((memKb / 1024 / 1024) + " GB of RAM installed.");
}
```

Comment: ***Thank you!*** I was looking for exactly this but everywhere I can only see how to find the total available memory rather than the installed one.

Comment: It doesn't work well on my virtual machine though, despite functioning perfectly on the main one.

Answer (score 33):

For those who are using `.net Core 3.0` there is no need to use `PInvoke` platform in order to get the available physical memory. The `GC` class has added a new method `GC.GetGCMemoryInfo` that returns a `GCMemoryInfo Struct` with `TotalAvailableMemoryBytes` as a property. This property returns the total available memory for the garbage collector.(same value as  MEMORYSTATUSEX)

```
var gcMemoryInfo = GC.GetGCMemoryInfo();
long installedMemory = gcMemoryInfo.TotalAvailableMemoryBytes;
// it will give the size of memory in MB
var physicalMemory = (double) installedMemory / 1048576.0;
```

Comment: My favorite answer. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, if your app is compiled for x86 / 32-bit process but running on a 64-bit machine, then this will not return the true total system memory installed. In my case, instead of returning 32 GB it returned 2 GB.

Comment: Note that you'll also need a 'using system;' for this code to work.

Comment: This does give installed capacity on local machine, however when this piece of code is inside Azure Function, it is not giving correct value, something to be aware of.

Answer (score 32):

If you happen to be using Mono, then you might be interested to know that Mono 2.8 (to be released later this year) will have a performance counter which reports the physical memory size on all the platforms Mono runs on (including Windows). You would retrieve the value of the counter using this code snippet:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class app
{
   static void Main ()
   {
       var pc = new PerformanceCounter ("Mono Memory", "Total Physical Memory");
       Console.WriteLine ("Physical RAM (bytes): {0}", pc.RawValue);
   }
}
```

If you are interested in C code which provides the performance counter, it can be found [here](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/mono/mono/metadata/mono-perfcounters.c?r1=154243&r2=155566&pathrev=155566).

Comment: works fine on any linux system, even on ARM systems.

Comment: @harry4516 on my Ubuntu system, PerformanceCounter is not supported

Answer (score 16):

Another way to do this, is by using the .NET System.Management querying facilities:

```
string Query = "SELECT Capacity FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory";
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Query);

UInt64 Capacity = 0;
foreach (ManagementObject WniPART in searcher.Get())
{
    Capacity += Convert.ToUInt64(WniPART.Properties["Capacity"].Value);
}

return Capacity;
```

Comment: This is throwing a System.Management.ManagementException Out of Memory on my machine. Any ideas?

Comment: I like this one. No need to reference `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices`. And as one-liner `var Capacity = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT Capacity FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory").Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().Sum(x => Convert.ToInt64(x.Properties["Capacity"].Value));`

Answer (score 7):

you can simply use this code to get those information, just add the reference

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices;
```

and the simply use the following code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getAvailableRAM();
    }

    public void getAvailableRAM()
    {
        ComputerInfo CI = new ComputerInfo();
        ulong mem = ulong.Parse(CI.TotalPhysicalMemory.ToString());
        richTextBox1.Text = (mem / (1024*1024) + " MB").ToString();
    }
```

Comment: not found in .net 4.6 version. I mean it gives ComputerInfo namespace is not found. even more... namespace 'Devices' is doesnt exist.

Answer (score 6):

```
// use `/ 1048576` to get ram in MB
// and `/ (1048576 * 1024)` or `/ 1048576 / 1024` to get ram in GB
private static String getRAMsize()
{
    ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_ComputerSystem");
    ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
    foreach (ManagementObject item in moc)
    {
       return Convert.ToString(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(item.Properties["TotalPhysicalMemory"].Value) / 1048576, 0)) + " MB";
    }

    return "RAMsize";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use 'WMI'.

I found a 'snippet'.

```vb
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _ 
& strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
Set colComputer = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")

For Each objComputer in colComputer 
  strMemory = objComputer.TotalPhysicalMemory
Next
```

Comment: Note that `Set` is no longer needed for VB.NET, is this VB6 code?

Answer (score 4):

Solution working on **Linux (.Net Core)**.
Inspired by [GitHub/Hardware.Info](https://github.com/Jinjinov/Hardware.Info).
Optimized to have minimal memory allocation and avg retrieval takes 0.020 ms.

```
private static readonly object _linuxMemoryLock = new();
private static readonly char[] _arrayForMemInfoRead = new char[200];

public static void GetBytesCountOnLinux(out ulong availableBytes, out ulong totalBytes)
{
    lock (_linuxMemoryLock) // lock because of reusing static fields due to optimization
    {
        totalBytes = GetBytesCountFromLinuxMemInfo(token: "MemTotal:", refreshFromFile: true);
        availableBytes = GetBytesCountFromLinuxMemInfo(token: "MemAvailable:", refreshFromFile: false);
    }
}

private static ulong GetBytesCountFromLinuxMemInfo(string token, bool refreshFromFile)
{
    // NOTE: Using the linux file /proc/meminfo which is refreshed frequently and starts with:
    //MemTotal:        7837208 kB
    //MemFree:          190612 kB
    //MemAvailable:    5657580 kB

    var readSpan = _arrayForMemInfoRead.AsSpan();

    if (refreshFromFile)
    {
        using var fileStream = new FileStream("/proc/meminfo", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

        using var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8, leaveOpen: true);

        reader.ReadBlock(readSpan);
    }

    var tokenIndex = readSpan.IndexOf(token);

    var fromTokenSpan = readSpan.Slice(tokenIndex + token.Length);

    var kbIndex = fromTokenSpan.IndexOf("kB");

    var notTrimmedSpan = fromTokenSpan.Slice(0, kbIndex);

    var trimmedSpan = notTrimmedSpan.Trim(' ');

    var kBytesCount = ulong.Parse(trimmedSpan);

    var bytesCount = kBytesCount * 1024;

    return bytesCount;
}
```

---

**Linux and Windows together** - for easy copy paste. Windows code taken from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/105109/2094687).

```
public static void GetRamBytes(out ulong availableBytes, out ulong totalBytes)
{
    if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
    {
        GetBytesCountOnLinux(out availableBytes, out totalBytes);
    }
    else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
    {
        GetBytesCountOnWindows(out availableBytes, out totalBytes);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Not implemented for OS: " + Environment.OSVersion);
    }
}

private static readonly object _winMemoryLock = new();
private static readonly MEMORYSTATUSEX _memStatus = new();

private static void GetBytesCountOnWindows(out ulong availableBytes, out ulong totalBytes)
{
    lock (_winMemoryLock) // lock because of reusing the static class _memStatus
    {
        GlobalMemoryStatusEx(_memStatus);

        availableBytes = _memStatus.ullAvailPhys;
        totalBytes = _memStatus.ullTotalPhys;
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private class MEMORYSTATUSEX
{
    public uint dwLength;
    public uint dwMemoryLoad;
    public ulong ullTotalPhys;
    public ulong ullAvailPhys;
    public ulong ullTotalPageFile;
    public ulong ullAvailPageFile;
    public ulong ullTotalVirtual;
    public ulong ullAvailVirtual;
    public ulong ullAvailExtendedVirtual;

    public MEMORYSTATUSEX()
    {
        this.dwLength = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MEMORYSTATUSEX));
    }
}

[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool GlobalMemoryStatusEx([In] [Out] MEMORYSTATUSEX lpBuffer);
```

Answer (score 2):

This function (`ManagementQuery`) works on Windows XP and later:

```
private static string ManagementQuery(string query, string parameter, string scope = null) {
    string result = string.Empty;
    var searcher = string.IsNullOrEmpty(scope) ? new ManagementObjectSearcher(query) : new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
    foreach (var os in searcher.Get()) {
        try {
            result = os[parameter].ToString();
        }
        catch {
            //ignore
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(BytesToMb(Convert.ToInt64(ManagementQuery("SELECT TotalPhysicalMemory FROM Win32_ComputerSystem", "TotalPhysicalMemory", "root\\CIMV2"))));
```

Comment: where does that `BytesToMb` function come from?

Comment: @dlatikay it's inner fuction: 
   private static double BytesToMb(long bytes) {
            return Math.Round(bytes / 1024d / 1024d, 2);
   }

Answer (score 2):

**Compatible with .Net and Mono (tested with Win10/FreeBSD/CentOS)**

Using `ComputerInfo` source code and `PerformanceCounter`s for Mono and as backup for .Net:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;

public class SystemMemoryInfo
{
    private readonly PerformanceCounter _monoAvailableMemoryCounter;
    private readonly PerformanceCounter _monoTotalMemoryCounter;
    private readonly PerformanceCounter _netAvailableMemoryCounter;

    private ulong _availablePhysicalMemory;
    private ulong _totalPhysicalMemory;

    public SystemMemoryInfo()
    {
        try
        {
            if (PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists("Mono Memory"))
            {
                _monoAvailableMemoryCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Mono Memory", "Available Physical Memory");
                _monoTotalMemoryCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Mono Memory", "Total Physical Memory");
            }
            else if (PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists("Memory"))
            {
                _netAvailableMemoryCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available Bytes");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // ignored
        }
    }

    public ulong AvailablePhysicalMemory
    {
        [SecurityCritical]
        get
        {
            Refresh();

            return _availablePhysicalMemory;
        }
    }

    public ulong TotalPhysicalMemory
    {
        [SecurityCritical]
        get
        {
            Refresh();

            return _totalPhysicalMemory;
        }
    }

    [SecurityCritical]
    [DllImport("Kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern void GlobalMemoryStatus(ref MEMORYSTATUS lpBuffer);

    [SecurityCritical]
    [DllImport("Kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GlobalMemoryStatusEx(ref MEMORYSTATUSEX lpBuffer);

    [SecurityCritical]
    private void Refresh()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_monoTotalMemoryCounter != null && _monoAvailableMemoryCounter != null)
            {
                _totalPhysicalMemory = (ulong) _monoTotalMemoryCounter.NextValue();
                _availablePhysicalMemory = (ulong) _monoAvailableMemoryCounter.NextValue();
            }
            else if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major < 5)
            {
                var memoryStatus = MEMORYSTATUS.Init();
                GlobalMemoryStatus(ref memoryStatus);

                if (memoryStatus.dwTotalPhys > 0)
                {
                    _availablePhysicalMemory = memoryStatus.dwAvailPhys;
                    _totalPhysicalMemory = memoryStatus.dwTotalPhys;
                }
                else if (_netAvailableMemoryCounter != null)
                {
                    _availablePhysicalMemory = (ulong) _netAvailableMemoryCounter.NextValue();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var memoryStatusEx = MEMORYSTATUSEX.Init();

                if (GlobalMemoryStatusEx(ref memoryStatusEx))
                {
                    _availablePhysicalMemory = memoryStatusEx.ullAvailPhys;
                    _totalPhysicalMemory = memoryStatusEx.ullTotalPhys;
                }
                else if (_netAvailableMemoryCounter != null)
                {
                    _availablePhysicalMemory = (ulong) _netAvailableMemoryCounter.NextValue();
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // ignored
        }
    }

    private struct MEMORYSTATUS
    {
        private uint dwLength;
        internal uint dwMemoryLoad;
        internal uint dwTotalPhys;
        internal uint dwAvailPhys;
        internal uint dwTotalPageFile;
        internal uint dwAvailPageFile;
        internal uint dwTotalVirtual;
        internal uint dwAvailVirtual;

        public static MEMORYSTATUS Init()
        {
            return new MEMORYSTATUS
            {
                dwLength = checked((uint) Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MEMORYSTATUS)))
            };
        }
    }

    private struct MEMORYSTATUSEX
    {
        private uint dwLength;
        internal uint dwMemoryLoad;
        internal ulong ullTotalPhys;
        internal ulong ullAvailPhys;
        internal ulong ullTotalPageFile;
        internal ulong ullAvailPageFile;
        internal ulong ullTotalVirtual;
        internal ulong ullAvailVirtual;
        internal ulong ullAvailExtendedVirtual;

        public static MEMORYSTATUSEX Init()
        {
            return new MEMORYSTATUSEX
            {
                dwLength = checked((uint) Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MEMORYSTATUSEX)))
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET has a memory amount limit that it can access.
In Windows XP 2GB was the "hard ceiling".
For instance: You could have 4 GB in it, and it would kill the app when it hit 2GB.

Also in 64 bit mode, there is a percentage of memory you can use out of the system, so I'm not sure if you can ask for the whole thing or if this is specifically guarded against.

Comment: /No/.  Total physical memory means the actual memory physically installed.

Comment: Actually, DevelopingChris is correct. If you call GlobalMemoryStatusEx on a XP machine with 4 Gig of Ram, it will report that there is only 3 Gig installed.

Comment: Also, using WMI to query TotalPhysicalMemory in Win32_ComputerSystem or Win32_LogicalMemoryConfiguration also produces the wrong result.

Comment: thank you, its not that I don't understand the question its that you have to use a different source for the information other than a .net library.

Comment: This answer is the only one that makes sense. I tired it now on Win 64 8Gb ram using VisualBasic referenced. I get junk negative values.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody has mentioned [GetPerformanceInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms683210%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) yet. [PInvoke signatures](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/psapi/GetPerformanceInfo.html) are available.

This function makes the following system-wide information available:

- CommitTotal
- CommitLimit
- CommitPeak
- PhysicalTotal
- PhysicalAvailable
- SystemCache
- KernelTotal
- KernelPaged
- KernelNonpaged
- PageSize
- HandleCount
- ProcessCount
- ThreadCount

`PhysicalTotal` is what the OP is looking for, although the value is the number of pages, so to convert to bytes, multiply by the `PageSize` value returned.

Answer (score -2):

Here is another, much more simply way, using .net:

```
// total memory
long totalPhysicalMemory = My.Computer.Info.TotalPhysicalMemory;

// unused memory
long availablePhysicalMemory = My.Computer.Info.AvailablePhysicalMemory;

// used memory
long usedMemory = totalPhysicalMemory - availablePhysicalMemory;
```

Comment: What namespace is that from? Is using a library?

Comment: documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.computerinfo.totalphysicalmemory?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0   - but its tied to vb.net so perhaps why this response is not getting any love :-)

Answer (score -3):

`var ram = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_PhysicalMemory") .Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().First();`

|

`var a = Convert.ToInt64(ram["Capacity"]) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;`

(richiede System.Managment.dll come riferimento, testato su C# con Framework 4.7.2)

questa procedura salva in "a" la ram totale presente in GB

---

`ulong memory() { return new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo().TotalPhysicalMemory; }`

|

`var b = Convert.ToDecimal(memory()) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;`

(richiede Microsoft.VisualBasics.dll come riferimento, testato su C# Framework 4.7.2)

questa procedura salva in "b" il valore della ram in GB effettivamente disponibile

---

Comment: You should write the question in English.

Answer (score -4):

```
/*The simplest way to get/display total physical memory in VB.net (Tested)

public sub get_total_physical_mem()

    dim total_physical_memory as integer

    total_physical_memory=CInt((My.Computer.Info.TotalPhysicalMemory) / (1024 * 1024))
    MsgBox("Total Physical Memory" + CInt((My.Computer.Info.TotalPhysicalMemory) / (1024 * 1024)).ToString + "Mb" )
end sub
*/


//The simplest way to get/display total physical memory in C# (converted Form http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp)

public void get_total_physical_mem()
{
    int total_physical_memory = 0;

    total_physical_memory = Convert.ToInt32((My.Computer.Info.TotalPhysicalMemory) /  (1024 * 1024));
    Interaction.MsgBox("Total Physical Memory" + Convert.ToInt32((My.Computer.Info.TotalPhysicalMemory) / (1024 * 1024)).ToString() + "Mb");
}
```

Comment: That might be thanks to online Visual Basic to CShap converters.