# Retrieving Total amount of RAM on a computer

Tags: c#, performancecounter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - How do you get total amount of RAM the computer has?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105031/c-sharp-how-do-you-get-total-amount-of-ram-the-computer-has)

The following would retrieve how much ram is available:

```
PerformanceCounter ramCounter;
ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
Console.WriteLine("Total RAM: " + ramCounter.NextValue().ToString() + " MB\n\n");
```

Of course we will have to use the System.Diagnostics; class.

Does performancecounter have any functionality for retrieving the amount of RAM of a particular machine? I'm not talking about the amount of ram used or unused. I'm talking about the amount of ram the machine has.

Comment: Check [this][1] .


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105031/c-sharp-how-do-you-get-total-amount-of-ram-the-computer-has

Comment: This have been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105031/c-sharp-how-do-you-get-total-amount-of-ram-the-computer-has

Comment: Yes it has but not by using the performance counter class. I'm trying to tackle this from the performance counter class directly and not via visual basic DLL.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This information is already available directly in the .NET framework, you might as well use it.  Project + Add Reference, select Microsoft.VisualBasic.

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("You have {0} bytes of RAM",
            new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo().TotalPhysicalMemory);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

And no, it doesn't turn your C# code into vb.net.

Comment: Could you advise me on how to set my topic as answered/completed?

Comment: The question asks for amount of RAM on a machine, so this should be `new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo().TotalPhysicalMemory` rather than AvailablePhysicalMemory which displays amount of bytes currently allocated.

Comment: Does not work in .NET 3.0+. [The entire `Devices` namespace has been removed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/visualbasic#types-in-microsoftvisualbasicdevices-namespace-not-available).

Comment: Target .NET Core 5 instead.

Answer (score 2):

you can try like this

Add a Reference to System.Management.

```
private static void DisplayTotalRam()
{
  string Query = "SELECT MaxCapacity FROM Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray";
  ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Query);
  foreach (ManagementObject WniPART in searcher.Get())
  {
    UInt32 SizeinKB = Convert.ToUInt32(WniPART.Properties["MaxCapacity"].Value);
    UInt32 SizeinMB = SizeinKB / 1024;
    UInt32 SizeinGB = SizeinMB / 1024;
    Console.WriteLine("Size in KB: {0}, Size in MB: {1}, Size in GB: {2}", SizeinKB, SizeinMB, SizeinGB);
  }
}
```

Comment: For some reason this is retrieving the wrong value, suppose to be 3.34 g, it's retrieving 4 gb. I have some code to do this and was using it in an application of mines on my laptop for 6 years and working fine. Added some more RAM to my computer and suddenly doesn't work again. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This is not retrieving the currently installed memory this is retrieving the max supported amount of memory that can be installed to the mainboard.