# How to use C# to set the available Physical Memory to designated size?

Tags: c#, windows, memory, memory-management

Is it possible to use C# to write a program which could expropriate designated size physical memory?

Comment: Did you tried _anything_ so far? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: What is the need of doing this ? Normally the net runtime manages all kinds of (physical) memory allocation. And this works really good. Thats also the reason why you shouldn'T even use GC.Collect. The Feature you search is much more critical. Depending on what you are doing I would recommend that you use a diffrent language and have a second look if you really need this functionality

Comment: I need to investigate the behavior of a program when the free physical memory was gradually decreased.

Comment: Check if [VirtualLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366895(v=vs.85).aspx) helps you... Also it is unclear what you are really trying to test (probably to you too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to refer this question>

[Array size based on available physical memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673039/array-size-based-on-available-physical-memory)

Here array is used based on available physical memory.

Refer those answers. Might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

C# is not an appropriate language for low level memory manipulation.