# How to get Free Memory and CPU usage without PerformanceCounter?

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter

I have Windows XP which do not provide the Categories Processor or Memory, and I cannot bring it to show them 
(I'm not allowed to edit the registry nor to change System Files)

Is there any way to get the actual CPU usage and Free Memory without using PerformanceCounter?

I'm using `.NET 3.5` and `C#` on Windows XP SP2

Comment: dumb question but what's wrong with PerformanceCounter? permissions issue / something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you be able to use native win32 API calls?  If so then they would provide the information your after.

See the following article: [CodeProject: Calling API functions using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1285/Calling-API-functions-using-C)

Comment: thank you, with the API I already got the Free Memory working.
I'm going to try out more tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

To get the Processor usage without performance counter using WMI, Look at win32_Processor class. and if you want to see the total memory available use `GC.GetTotalMemory - Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64`;

Comment: your code returns -26 MB of Free Mem, I also don't get why you substract the current process.
I understand that GC.GetTotalMemory returns the number of reserved bytes. Does your code only return the memory available to .NET?
can you explain what you are doing?

Comment: see the following link to get the total memory and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105031/c-sharp-how-do-you-get-total-amount-of-ram-the-computer-has

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .net 4 and you are only interested in what your current app domain is doing then you can use this:

```
this.AppDomain.MonitoringTotalProcessorTime
```

See [MSDN Documentation MonitoringTotalProcessorTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.monitoringtotalprocessortime.aspx)

Comment: thank you, but I don't want to know anything about my application, but totals and I'm also forced to use .net 3.5