# I am trying to get the total installed ram

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the total installed memory. I have 6GB installed but this is returning 5.47GB. What can I do to fix this? I did a build on a x64 PC and am running the app on a x64 PC.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            internal class MEMORYSTATUSEX
            {
                public uint dwLength;
                public uint dwMemoryLoad;
                public ulong ullTotalPhys;
                public ulong ullAvailPhys;
                public ulong ullTotalPageFile;
                public ulong ullAvailPageFile;
                public ulong ullTotalVirtual;
                public ulong ullAvailVirtual;
                public ulong ullAvailExtendedVirtual;

                public MEMORYSTATUSEX()
                {
                    this.dwLength = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(NativeMethods.MEMORYSTATUSEX));
                }
            }

            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            internal static extern Boolean GlobalMemoryStatusEx([In, Out] MEMORYSTATUSEX lpBuffer);

public static String GetTotalRam
            {
                get
                {
                    ulong installedMemory = 0;
                    NativeMethods.MEMORYSTATUSEX memStatus = new NativeMethods.MEMORYSTATUSEX();
                    if (NativeMethods.GlobalMemoryStatusEx(memStatus))
                    {
                        installedMemory = memStatus.ullTotalPhys;
                    }
                    return ConvertBytes(installedMemory);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105031/how-do-you-get-total-amount-of-ram-the-computer-has

Comment: I tried everything in that post with 5.47GB as a result as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your posted method gives you the total *available* memory, which is not exactly the same as the total *installed* memory.

To get the amount of installed memory, you can use a call to the [GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc300158(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

I think you'll find the *Remarks* section from that link interesting:

> The **GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory** function retrieves the amount of physically installed RAM from the computer's SMBIOS firmware tables. This can differ from the amount reported by the **GlobalMemoryStatusEx** function, which sets the ullTotalPhys member of the MEMORYSTATUSEX structure to the amount of physical memory that is available for the operating system to use. ***The amount of memory available to the operating system can be less than the amount of memory physically installed in the computer*** because the BIOS and some drivers may reserve memory as I/O regions for memory-mapped devices, making the memory unavailable to the operating system and applications.

**EDIT: Added Sample code**

Modified from the code found [here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory.html):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory(out long TotalMemoryInKilobytes);

static void Main()
{
    long memKb;
    GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory(out memKb);
    Console.WriteLine((memKb / 1024 / 1024) + " GB of RAM installed.");
}
```

Comment: What do I type in native methods exactly to use that?

Comment: can i find RAM from registry ?

Answer (score 0):

Although this seems weird add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` and use this:

```
return new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo().TotalPhysicalMemory;
```

Comment: I am getting the same 5.47GB with that too!

Comment: you probably have 512MB allocated for graphics or something like this, do you have an integrated graphics controller on your cpu?

Comment: Yes I do I have a AMD A10. My computer is a laptop. How do I return the exact allocated amount of that so I can add that amount to my total?