# Total amount of RAM on a computer in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

On .NET Framework we could use the [TotalPhysicalMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.computerinfo.totalphysicalmemory(v=vs.110).aspx) property from the [ComputerInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.computerinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class like the code snippet below:

```
var totalPhysicalMemory = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo().TotalPhysicalMemory;
```

I saw there was an [API Proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22660) for this feature but don't think it is out yet.

Is there a work around for this .NET Core or maybe something that I might have missed out?

Comment: I just checked how I was doing this in our codebase (in .NET framework, but I knew it isn't using VisualBasic components). Found that it's implemented by calling native GlobalMemoryStatusEx() function...

Comment: It looks as though (at least, right now), that TotalPhysicalMemory is .NET Framework and Mono specific (as per: https://apisof.net/catalog/Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo.TotalPhysicalMemory).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get total amount of RAM the computer has?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105031/how-do-you-get-total-amount-of-ram-the-computer-has)

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/105109/542251) is reliant om COM components so should work on Core and non-core.

Comment: I put some work into an implementation of `ComputerInfo` for .NET Standard on Linux, macOS, and Windows. https://github.com/NickStrupat/ComputerInfo

Comment: @NickStrupat super idea, it is in prerelease state, so does it work or is it no longer developed?

Comment: @Lumo it works but I never did figure out the exact analogs for some of the metrics in Linux and macOS.