# Profiling memory usage of ASP.NET Core 6 site in production

Tags: profiling, azure-application-insights, asp.net-core-6.0, memory-profiling

We have an ASP.NET Core 6 site in production where the memory and cpu usage looks this this:

[image]

The cpu peaks seems more to be a consequence of memory not being available and we see `OutOfMemoryException` in the logs.

We are using Application Insights but I don't find a way to see what data is getting stored in memory. The total memory consumption obviously comes from multiple things (operating system etc) but is there a way to log what data the ASP.NET Core application is storing?

Comment: You can always log info on the logger, in different locations of your code, with the total memory usage. To get this info you can use the following method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59073095/3231884

Answer (score 1):

> Profiling memory usage of ASP.NET Core 6

Created and deployed Azure App Service `.NetCore 6` with Application Insights.

***Check the below steps to enable Profiler for the deployed App Service***

- Enable the `Always on` option.
  [image]
- Enable Profiler option from Application Insights.
- Navigate to Your `App Service` => `Application Insights` => Make sure you have Enabled `Application Insights` .
  [image]
- Turn on the Profiler option to `on`.

[image]

***Transaction Search***
`Application Insights` => `Transaction Search`

[image]

- In your `Application Insights` => `Performance` => `Profiler`
  [image]

Triggers => set `CPU`, `Memory` and `Sampling` to `On` and click on `Profile now`.

[image]

[image]

- Click on the session to get the detailed Info.
  [image]

References taken from [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/profiler/profiler-overview)

Comment: Very comprehensive answer. Can you elaborate on how I can see what the application is storing in the memory?